# How can I solve this Solr/MySQL race condition?

Tags: php, mysql, solr, race-condition

I'm experiencing a very strange problem whereby my Solr index is not able to see a change just written to a MySQL database on another connection.

Here is the chain of events:

1. The user initiates an action on the website that causes a row to be added to a table in MySQL.
2. The row is added via `mysql_query()` (no transactions). If I query the database again from the same connection I can naturally see the change I just made.*
3. A call is immediately sent to a Solr instance via curl to tell it to do a partial update of its index using the Data Import Handler.
4. Solr connects to the MySQL database via a separate JDBC connection (same credentials and everything) and executes a query for all records updated since its last update.

At this point, however, the results returned to Solr do *not* include the last-added row, unless I insert a `sleep()` call immediately after making the change to the database and before sending the message to Solr.

*Note that if I actually *do* query the database at this point though, this takes enough time for the change to actually be picked up by Solr. The same occurs if I simply `sleep(1)` (for one second).

What I'm looking for is some reliable solution that can allow me to make sure the change will be seen by Solr before sending it the refresh message. According to all documentation I've found, however, the call to `mysql_query()` should already be atomic and synchronous and should not return control to PHP until the database has been updated. Therefore there doesn't appear to be any function I can call to force this.

Does anyone have any advice/ideas? I'm banging my head over this one.

Answer (score 1):

Check what the auto-commit is set to when inserting the record. Chances are the record just inserted is in the same database session and thus is seen (but isn't committed). After this, some event causes the commit to occur and hence another thread/session can then "see" the record. Also check the transaction isolation level settings.

Comment: `@@AUTOCOMMIT` is 1, but the change is still not being picked up by the second connection.

Comment: In a separate command-line type MySQL window, after you think the new record is inserted/committed, run a query to verify. If the row is not there or not updated, then it is a basic commit or transaction-isolation setting issue. If it is there and then Solr does not see it, it is a problem in the Solr query that may be reading some (old) cached value. Based on the earlier comment this may be the case since after some time it appear to be picked up (reflecting a cache timeout case).

Answer (score 1):

I typically do not use the Data Import handler and would have the update in the website trigger a mechanism (either internal or external) to update the record into Solr using the appropriate [Solr Client](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) for the programming language being used. I have personally not had a lot of luck with the Data Import Handler in the past and as a result have preferred to use custom code for synchronizing Solr with the corresponding data storage platform.

Comment: Interesting. I'm basically coming into this after someone else designed it. I guess using the DIH was her idea and am not really aware of the alternatives. I will look into that for sure, but for the moment I just need to get this working. :)